# accessing IFRAME in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I'm trying to do the following. Click on the Iframe and then type text into it using VBA

[image]

so basically i'm trying to just add text similar to the above image.

below is the code

```
appIE.document.frames("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633e_contentIframe").document.querySelector ("RADEDITORSTYLESHEET0").Click
SendKeys "testing"






<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633eCenter" class="reContent" style="height: 15.1667em;">
                                <label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633eContentHiddenTextarea" style="display:none;">RadEditor hidden textarea</label><textarea id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633eContentHiddenTextarea" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633e" rows="4" cols="20" style="display:none;"></textarea>
                            <iframe frameborder="0" src="javascript:'<html></html>';" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633e_contentIframe" title="Rich text editor with ID ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633e" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.</iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like so, but not suggesting this as the answer as cant access the web page to try/test.

```
Dim f As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement
Dim e As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set f = appIE.document.frames("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_e522acff_b38a_4e8d_9c7f_484deb53633e_contentIframe")
Set e = f.querySelector("RADEDITORSTYLESHEET0")
e.document.innerHTML = "testing"
```

Comment: tried this, didn't work. The error is Method 'frames' of object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed.